# Collection to string using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }   
}

List<Person> PersonList = new List<Perso>();
PersonList.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "aa", LastName = "AA" } );
PersonList.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "bb", LastName = "BB" } );
```

I'd like get a string with a comma separator for the LastName, using Linq, the result look like:
AA,BB

Thanks,

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4:

```
string lastNames = string.Join(",", PersonList.Select(x => x.LastName));
```

If you're using .NET 3.5:

```
string lastNames = string.Join(",", PersonList.Select(x => x.LastName)
                                              .ToArray());
```

(Basically .NET 4 had some extra overloads added to [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c.aspx).)

Answer (score 10):

You can use

```
PersonList.Select(p => p.LastName).Aggregate((s1,s2) => s1 + ", " + s2);
```

Answer (score 8):

To concatenate string items, with separators, you can use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)

In .NET 3.5 and below, this takes an array as the second parameter, but in 4.0 it has an overload that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`, where `T` in this case is `String`.

Armed with this information, here's the code you want.

For .NET 3.5:

```
string result = String.Join(", ",
    (from p in PersonList
     select p.LastName).ToArray());
```

For .NET 4.0 you can omit the call to ToArray:

```
string result = String.Join(", ",
    from p in PersonList
    select p.LastName);
```

If you want to drop the LINQ-syntax and just use the LINQ extension methods, here's the same in that variant:

For .NET 3.5:

```
string result = String.Join(", ", PersonList.Select(p => p.LastName).ToArray());
```

For .NET 4.0 you can omit the call to ToArray:

```
string result = String.Join(", ", PersonList.Select(p => p.LastName));
```

**Note**: The 3.5 variants above of course works in 4.0 as well, they did not remove or replace the old method, they just added one for the typical case.